# Connecting to my Home Server using socket programming

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming

I'm writing an Android app for home automation wherein the app connects to my home PC via sockets so that I can control various home appliances on the move. My question is how do I make my home dynamic IP static and accessible to other devices on the internet so that I can make this connection. Thanks! :)

Comment: read about android c2dm.

Comment: Thanks. However, in general for non-android devices what do I do? For instance, if I want to connect to my Home PC from another PC via the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a free dynamic DNS service such as [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html). The basic idea is that you install an application on your server that keeps your IP address up-to-date on No-IP, so they can maintain a DNS record that points to your server. It'll give you a subdomain, not a [second-level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain), but that should be Good Enough.

Comment: Hey I did the configuration as you mentioned and it works. Thanks! When I put in the IP no-ip provided me into my browser, it goes to my ISP's DSL router page as it should. Any idea how I can make it go to the Apache /var/www/index.html file so that my Home PC is converted to a web server?

Comment: You're really getting into the realm of server & network configuration. How about asking a question on [the right Stack Exchange site](http://s.tk/su)? `;-)`